# Copy/move one environment to another

Tags: r

I would like to ask if it is possible to copy/move all the objects of one environment to another, at once. For example:

```
f1 <- function() {
    print(v1)
    print(v2)
}

f2 <- function() {
    v1 <- 1
    v2 <- 2

    # environment(f1)$v1 <- v1         # It works
    # environment(f1)$v2 <- v2         # It works
    
    environment(f1) <- environment(f2) # It does not work
}

f2()
f1()
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There seem to be at least 3 different things you can do:

1. Clone an environment (create an exact duplicate)
2. Copy the content of one environment to another environment
3. Share the same environment

To clone:

```
# Make the source env
e1 <- new.env()
e1$foo <- 1
e1$.bar <- 2   # a hidden name
ls(e1) # only shows "foo"

# This will clone e1
e2 <- as.environment(as.list(e1, all.names=TRUE))

# Check it...
identical(e1, e2) # FALSE
e2$foo
e2$.bar
```

To copy the content, you can do what @gsk showed. But again, the `all.names` flag is useful:

```
# e1 is source env, e2 is dest env
for(n in ls(e1, all.names=TRUE)) assign(n, get(n, e1), e2)
```

To share the environment is what @koshke did. This is probably often much more useful. The result is the same as if creating a local function:

```
f2 <- function() {
  v1 <- 1 
  v2 <- 2

  # This local function has access to v1 and v2
  flocal <- function() {
    print(v1)
    print(v2)
  }

  return(flocal)
} 

f1 <- f2()
f1() # prints 1 and 2
```

Comment: This won't work if the environments contains unevaluated promises

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
f2 <- function() {
    v1 <- 1
    v2 <- 2
    environment(f1) <<- environment()
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The other current solutions who actually attempt to make a copy will all fail if the environment contains promises, because they convert environments to lists.

{rlang} has now `env_clone()` which will clone the environment, including promises and active bindings.
It doesn't do a deep copy though, and clones the environment by default with a new parent, you can do `rlang::env_clone(env, parent.env(env))` to keep the same parent though.

I recommend the above, find below a previous solution from when {rlang} had more limitations. It should behave similar but provides an option for deep copy, with caveats given at the bottom.

---

The solution below works in these cases. Following @geoffrey-poole 's idea I propose an argument to deep copy or not, and I showcase the function on a test case.

It uses unexported functions from the package *{pryr}*. I don't know of a base R equivalent.

**The function**

```r
clone_env <- function(env, deep = FALSE) {
  is_unevaled_promise <- function(name, env) {
    pryr:::is_promise2(name, env) && !pryr:::promise_evaled(name, env)
  }
  # create new environment with same parent
  clone <- new.env(parent = parent.env(env))
  for(obj in ls(env, all.names = TRUE)) {
    promise_lgl <- is_unevaled_promise(as.symbol(obj), env = env)
    if(promise_lgl) {
      # fetch promise expression and env
      promise_expr <- pryr:::promise_code(obj, env)
      promise_env  <- pryr:::promise_env(obj, env)

      # Assign this expression as a promise (delayed assignment) in our
      # cloned environment
      eval(bquote(
        delayedAssign(obj, .(promise_expr), eval.env = promise_env, assign.env = clone)))
    } else {
      obj_val <- get(obj, envir = env)
      if(is.environment(obj_val) && deep) {
        assign(obj, clone_env(obj_val, deep = TRUE),envir= clone)
      } else  {
        assign(obj, obj_val, envir= clone)
      }
    }
  }
  attributes(clone) <- attributes(env)
  clone
}
```

**Shallow copy**

Let's build an environment containing a character variable, a promise (note that `a` is undefined), and a nested environment.

```r
create_test_env <- function(x = a){
  y <- "original"
  nested_env <- new.env()
  nested_env$nested_value <- "original"
  environment()
}
env <- create_test_env()
ls(env)
#> [1] "nested_env" "x"          "y"

# clone it, with deep = FALSE
shallow_clone <- clone_env(env, deep = FALSE) 
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'pryr':
#>   method      from
#>   print.bytes Rcpp
ls(shallow_clone)
#> [1] "nested_env" "x"          "y"

# the promise was copied smoothly
a <- 42
shallow_clone$x
#> [1] 42

# We can change values independently
shallow_clone$y <- "modified"
env$y
#> [1] "original"

# except if we have nested environents!
shallow_clone$nested_env$nested_value <- "modified"
env$nested_env$nested_value
#> [1] "modified"
```

**Deep copy**

Let's do it all over again, but with a deep clone now, we see the nested values are distinct this time.

```r
env <- create_test_env()
deep_clone <- clone_env(env, deep = TRUE) 
a <- 42
deep_clone$x
#> [1] 42
deep_clone$y <- "modified"
env$y
#> [1] "original"
deep_clone$nested_env$nested_value <- "modified"
env$nested_env$nested_value
#> [1] "original"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

---

Note that the deep copy is not super robust:

- We should recursively explore every list object and look for environments to clone there too.
- What if we find `.GlobalEnv`, `.BaseNamespaceEnv` etc there, do we really want to clone those ? We could have an argument to feed arguments not to clone
- Attributes might contain environments too, and these are not deep copied

I haven't met the need to go further in the rabbit hole. I you need this feel free to edit or copy and improve into your own answer.

Answer (score 6):

The "clone" method posted by Tommy won't make a true (deep) clone when `e1` contains names that reference other environments. For instance, if `e1$nestedEnv` references an environment, `e2$nestedEnv` will reference the same environment, not a copy of that environment.  Thus, the name `e1$nestedEnv$bar` will reference the same memory location as `e2$nestedEnv$bar` and any new value assigned to `e1$nestedEnv$bar` will be reflected for `e2$nestedEnv$bar` as well.  This may be desirable behavior, but calling `e2` a clone of `e1` could be misleading.

Here is a function that will allow the user to make either a copy of an environment while also copying any nested environments (a "deep clone", using `deep = TRUE`), or just use the method proposed by Tommy to copy the environment while maintaining original references to any nested environments (using `deep = FALSE`).

The 'deep = TRUE' method uses `rapply` to recursively call `cloneEnv` on nested environment within `envir`, for as many levels as the environments are nested.  So, in the end, it recursively calls `rapply`, which is a bit of a mind bender, but works pretty well.

Note that if a nested environment contains a name that references a parent environment, using the "deep" method will never return from the recursive calls.  If I could have figured out a way to check for this, I would have included it...

Note, too, that environments can have attributes, so copying the attributes would be necessary for a true clone, which this solution also addresses.

```
cloneEnv <- function(envir, deep = T) {
  if(deep) {
    clone <- list2env(rapply(as.list(envir, all.names = TRUE), cloneEnv, classes = "environment", how = "replace"), parent = parent.env(envir))
  } else {
    clone <- list2env(as.list(envir, all.names = TRUE), parent = parent.env(envir))
  }
  attributes(clone) <- attributes(envir)
  return(clone)
}
```

An example:

Create environment `e1`, which also contains a nested environment:

```
e1 <- new.env()
e1$foo <- "Christmas"
e1$nestedEnv <- new.env()
e1$nestedEnv$bar <- "New Years"
```

Show the values for `foo` and `bar`:

```
e1$foo
[1] "Christmas"
e1$nestedEnv$bar
[1] "New Years"
```

Make a deep clone (i.e. `e2` contains makes a copy of `nestedEnv`)

```
e2 <- cloneEnv(e1, deep = TRUE)
```

`nestedEnv` in `e1` references a difference environment than `nestedEnv` in `e2`:

```
identical(e1$nestedEnv, e2$nestedEnv)
[1] FALSE
```

But the values are the same because `e2$nestedEnv` is a copy of `e1$nestedEnv`:

```
e2$foo
[1] "Christmas"
e2$nestedEnv$bar
[1] "New Years"
```

Change the values in `e2`:

```
e2$foo <- "Halloween"
e2$nestedEnv$bar <- "Thanksgiving"
```

And values in `e1` remain unchanged, again, because `e1$nestedEnv` points to a different environment than `e2$nestedEnv`:

```
e1$foo
[1] "Christmas"
e2$foo
[1] "Halloween"

e1$nestedEnv$bar
[1] "New Years"
e2$nestedEnv$bar
[1] "Thanksgiving"
```

Now, re-create `e1` using Tommy's method:

```
e2 <- cloneEnv(e1, deep = FALSE)
```

`nestedEnv` in `e2` points to the same environment as `nestedEnv` in `e1`:

```
identical(e1$nestedEnv, e2$nestedEnv)
[1] TRUE
```

Update the values in `e2` and `e2`'s `nestedEnv`:

```
e2$foo <- "Halloween"
e2$nestedEnv$bar <- "Thanksgiving"
```

Values of `foo` are independent:

```
e1$foo
[1] "Christmas"
e2$foo
[1] "Halloween"
```

but updating value `e2`'s `bar` has also updated `e1`'s `bar` because `e1$nestedEnv` and `e2$nestedEnv` reference (point to) the same environment.

```
e1$nestedEnv$bar
[1] "Thanksgiving"
e2$nestedEnv$bar
[1] "Thanksgiving"
```

Comment: This also fails if the environment contains unevaluated promises.

Answer (score 5):

You could use assign:

```
f1 <- function() {
  print(v1)
  print(v2)
}

f2 <- function() {
  v1 <- 1
  v2 <- 2

  for(obj in c("v1","v2")) {
    assign(obj,get(obj),envir=f1.env)
  }
}
```

If you don't want to list out the objects, `ls()` takes an environment argument.

And you'll have to figure out how to get f1.env to be an environment pointing inside f1 :-)

Comment: Thanks!  It was a fun question.  @kohske's solution seems more elegant (as always!).

Comment: @kohske Uh oh.  Maybe the `,envir` option doesn't do what I thought it did.  I'll look further.

Comment: @gsk3 probably `envir` option does what you thought, but `environment(f1)` is `.GlobalEnv`.

Comment: Maybe a more sophisticated matter is to pass to the other environment a copy of the memory reference of the variables and not the variables themselves.

Comment: For what it's worth, this answer seems to match the way I've seen it done internally in R code written by R core members ... so it may be "canonical". @kohske's is cleverer, but that makes me nervous.

Answer (score 3):

I use this function in my package to copy objects:

```
copyEnv <- function(from, to, names=ls(from, all.names=TRUE)) {
  mapply(assign, names, mget(names, from), list(to), 
         SIMPLIFY = FALSE, USE.NAMES = FALSE)
  invisible(NULL)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it:

```
environment(f1) <- environment(f2) # It does not work
```

Open the `f1` environment and run do this:

```
ls(load(f2))
```