# Updating an existing Rdata file

Tags: r, rdata

I have found myself in the position of needing to update one or two data objects in an Rdata file previously created using `save`. If I'm not careful to load the file I can forget to re-save some objects in the file. As an example, I'm working on a package with some objects stored in `sysdata.rda` (look-up tables for internal use which I do not want to export) and only want to worry about updating individual objects.

I haven't managed to work out if there is a standard way to do this, so created my own function.

```
resave <- function (..., list = character(), file = stop("'file' must be specified")) {
  # create a staging environment to load the existing R objects
  stage <- new.env()
  load(file, envir=stage)
  # get the list of objects to be "resaved"
  names <- as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]
  list <- c(list, names)
  # copy the objects to the staging environment
  lapply(list, function(obj) assign(obj, get(obj), stage))
  # save everything in the staging environment
  save(list=ls(stage, all.names=TRUE), file=file)
}
```

It does seem like overkill though. Is there a better/easier way to do this?

As an aside, am I right in assuming that a new environment created in the scope of a function is destroyed after the function call?

Comment: Does make one (or at least me :-) ) wonder why `save` doesn't have an "append" option. I'll ask r-help and get back here if there's a useful answer.

Comment: Ok, I looked:   https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2006-March/101259.html  gives basically the same suggestion as the answer @flodel provided.  Personally I'd like to see this folded in to the base `save` function as an "append =T" option, but it's not a big deal.

Comment: I used `as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L]` (copying from `save`). Looking at the mailing list response, `deparse` is used rather than `as.character`. What are the pros/cons of the two approaches?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here is a slightly shorter version:

```
resave <- function(..., list = character(), file) {
   previous  <- load(file)
   var.names <- c(list, as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L])
   for (var in var.names) assign(var, get(var, envir = parent.frame()))
   save(list = unique(c(previous, var.names)), file = file)
}
```

I took advantage of the fact the `load` function returns the name of the loaded variables, so I could use the function's environment instead of creating one. And when using `get`, I was careful to only look in the environment from which the function is called, i.e. `parent.frame()`.

Here is a simulation:

```
x1 <- 1
x2 <- 2
x3 <- 3
save(x1, x2, x3, file = "abc.RData")

x1 <- 10
x2 <- 20
x3 <- 30
resave(x1, x3, file = "abc.RData")

load("abc.RData")
x1
# [1] 10
x2
# [1] 2
x3
# [1] 30
```

Comment: Thanks! One question: why are the arguments `list` and `file` not in the function's environment?

Comment: They are in the function's environment, but I am careful not to save them: see that I only save `unique(c(previous, var.names))`.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a refactored version of @flodel's answer in the stackoverflow package. It uses environments explicitly to be a bit more defensive.

```
resave <- function(..., list = character(), file) {
  e <- new.env()
  load(file, e)
  list <- union(list, as.character(substitute((...)))[-1L])
  copyEnv(parent.frame(), e, list)
  save(list = ls(e, all.names=TRUE), envir = e, file = file)
}
```

Comment: `copyEnv`  doens't seem to exists in base R

Comment: It's in the stackoverflow package from http://stackoverflow.com/a/33465113/986793