# How to copy R's iterator

Tags: r, iterator

Usually all R's objects are immutable with copy-on-modify semantics. This is not true for `environments`, which have reference semantics. Iterators in R ([iterators package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/iterators/index.html)) are implemented using `environments` and are mutable. This can be confusing. Consider following simple example:

```
library(iterators)
it1 <- iter(1:4)
it2 <- it1

nextElem(it1)
# 1
nextElem(it2)
# 2
```

And this is not what most of R users expect. **The question is how to effectively make a copy of iterator?** 
For the moment I have messy solution (borrowed [this idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965577/r-copy-move-one-environment-to-another)) for simple case above:

```
it1 <- iter(1:4)
it2 <- it1
it2$state  <- as.environment(as.list(it1$state))
next_el(it1)
# 1
next_el(it2)
# 1
```

But I feel like I'm missing something, and it also doesn't look like general solution.

Comment: Simple answer: Don't make a copy of an iterator. If you still need that, you could wrap your code into a function and call it `copy`.

Comment: This question raised from here [#65](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/issues/65) and [#71](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/issues/71). Users confused by such behaviour. And I personally also don't like that.

Comment: Well, I suggest to follow the example of the data.table devs and provide a `copy` function. That could be what you use above or you could probably write a C function that copies an environment. Or if you don't mind another dependence, you could use `restorepoint::clone.environment`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended with reimplementation of iterators on top of [R6](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/index.html) (thanks to @hadley's suggestion on twitter). R6 includes handy `clone` method with `deep = c(TRUE, FALSE)` option. Someone interested can find examples [here](https://github.com/dselivanov/text2vec/blob/0.4/R/iterators.R).