# Is there a way to use a variable to name a data frame in R?

Tags: r

Basically I want to be able to do this.

```
a <- 1
data_frame_1 <- "some data"
a <- a+1
data_frame_2 <- "some data"
```

Where the 1 and 2 at the end of the data frame names are coming from the values of a. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: It is better to use a list of data frames.

Comment: Do not follow advice pointing you towards the use of `assign`. The same effect can be achieved in R, but you have to think a little differently as noted in the first comment. Create a list of data frames, which you can append to if necessary. You can set the names of the list elements using `setNames`.

Comment: [Here's a list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17559390/5325862) of reasons to not use `assign`

Answer (score 0):

As a simple example:

```
my_list <- list(data_frame_1,data_frame_2)
my_list <- setNames(my_list,paste0("data_frame_",1:2))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do this using `assign`. Check out these links for reference.

[Error in  : target of assignment expands to non-language object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27662162/error-in-my-code-target-of-assignment-expands-to-non-language-object)

[Create a variable name with "paste" in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510966/create-a-variable-name-with-paste-in-r)

```
assign(paste0("data_frame_",a), "some_data")
```

Comment: It's true that you *can* do this, but it's a pretty poor practice and there are better alternatives, such as creating a list

Comment: @camille Are you saying using ``assign()`` is always a poor practice? Because I am using it in a group of multiple functions that send an email and the function was really helpfull. Creating a list was not an option for my function tho. I just want to know why ``assign()`` got a bad reputation, thank you.

Comment: I don't know that I'd say it's always a poor practice, but I can't think of any good reasons to use it. My comment up top links to an SO post that goes through reasons against using it

Comment: @camille The following provides "a" good use, but certainly not useful in this case. https://stackoverflow.com/a/9966441/9555388