# Is there a way to clone "wrap" object created by simmer?

Tags: r

I have created parallel replicas of simmer simulation, same way like in [introduction to simmer](https://r-simmer.org/articles/simmer-01-introduction.html):

```r
library(parallel)
library(simmer)

envs <- mclapply(1:100, function(i) {
  simmer("SuperDuperSim") %>%
    add_resource("nurse", 1) %>%
    add_resource("doctor", 2) %>%
    add_resource("administration", 1) %>%
    add_generator("patient", patient, function() rnorm(1, 10, 2)) %>%
    run(80) %>%
    wrap()
})
```

Now each object in `envs` is not a `simmer` class, but a `wrap` class instead. I want to modify some part of each `envs` object without modifying original object, but any change in the property will affect original object.

How can I clone `wrap` object to introduce some changes into it's properties and leave original object unchanged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long research has shown that there is no explicit function which do exactly what I need for simmer objects. However, I have figured out that both `simmer` and `wrap` objects are of type `environment`. The obvious solution here is to clone the environment, which is answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965577/r-copy-move-one-environment-to-another) and assign same classes to newly created environment in order to make it looking like the original object.

Sample code:

```r
clonedEnvs <- lapply(envs, function(env) {
  result <- as.environment(as.list.environment(env, all.names = TRUE))
  structure(result, class = class(env))
})
```